# Php multilanguage: how store the active language?

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

i'm building a php switcher to add **multilanguage** capability to my site.

Every content in MySQL has a language-specific text that I want to retrieve according to the active language.

At the beginning, I thought to build a tailored **table in MySQL to store the languages status**.
For example:
ITALIAN 1
ENGLISH 0
..where 1 means that language is active, and 0 means is off.

Every time the user switch language, I call this table and change the language status. Then, at the end of the call, I refresh the page and php retrieve the right contents.

This seemed a good idea till I figured out that the languages status in MySQL could change every time a user switch. So, if a user is viewing the site in Italian, and other user switch to English at the same time, the first user will view the English as well.

My question is: how could I store the languages status for the specific user, avoiding change the languages status for every other user ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: think about user sessions

Comment: Have you considered cookies? Basically, unless you do authentication module to figure out who is browsing the page, you are left with sessions and cookies.

Comment: locale + session + GNU getText (i18n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the database.  Set a `$_SESSION` variable instead (and don't forget to call `session_start()` before you modify it).  [(Php Manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: The session part is correct. The database part is not. Sessions are temporary. You need to store it in a database in order to tie the language choice to the user's account.

Comment: I think I'll choose the SESSION method, unless users I meant are casual ones, not registered user or someone like that. I meant user that view the site. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

If you want a persistent save, add a "Lang" column on the user table

User(id, username, passhash, lang);

And just store their language settings there. If you have another table with languages you can use a foreign key to avoid integrity issues.

If you dont care about being persistent (If the user logs from other computer it defaults back to the default language) you can use either Session or Cookies.